# Pop up displayed is not covering the entire screen swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I am new to iOS development, I have displayed popup on click on button on screen, but it is not covering entire screen, code to show popup

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController
self.addChild(popOverVC)
popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
popOverVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Comment: Did you add any constraints for it?

Comment: No I have not added any constraints

Comment: You have to add constraints for it. Either by code or using the storyboard constraints.

Comment: added constrains to top of the view containing dialog. Solved the issue

Comment: For safety you should add constraints to the top, left, bottom and right. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add AutoLayout constraints. This snippet should help you.

```
addChild(childViewController)
view.addSubview(childView)
childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: childView.topAnchor).isActive = true
view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: childView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: childView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: childView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
childViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply present one over another:

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController
// This one makes popOverVC fullscreen. In some cases you would like to use `.overFullScreen` just test what fits your scenario better
popOverVC = .fullScreen
// if you need it without animation, just call with animated: false
self.present(popOverVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Also I'll recommend to read this article

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-presentviewcontroller?language=objc

and this

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621355-modalpresentationstyle?language=objc

to have better understating of what going on :)